# How to save results of an SQL query to a variable in VB.Net?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio

The Query I have is

```
SELECT COUNT(Forename) FROM PrisonerInformation
```

I've be able to run this query to my MS Access database and put the results into a DataGridView but I really need to put it into a variable, so that I can then output it to a textfile and do other things with the results of the query.

Comment: It looks like you want the [ExecuteScalar Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Hello! Please include the code showing how you get it successfully. EDIT: Andrew Morton beat me to the punchline. He's got the right answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The Using blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row of the result set. Simply assign that to a variable.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ForenameCount As Integer
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(Forename) FROM PrisonerInformation", cn)
            cn.Open()
            ForenameCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show(ForenameCount.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLDataReader to access the results, you could set an explicit name for the count column, then do something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(Forename) As 'CountForename' FROM PrisonerInformation
countVariable = int.Parse(myReader["CountForename"].ToString());
```